# How to Get the Access Token for Grap API for reading the excel data which is uploaded in SharePoint Document Library

Tags: graph, microsoft-graph-excel

I have tested in my Graph API explore I am able to get the response of my excel data but when I add the same code in the ajax call it is not working.

When I did in the postman it worked but it need the access token which is getting generated in the Graph explore automatically once we user had logged in and if I take that token and hit in the postman or in my code it is giving me the response.

So someone can help me how to get that access token which is generate in the graph explore ?

Comment: Hi ZMS, can you provide details about your solution - what kind of solution it is - provider hosted app, SPFx solution or normal API call that you are adding in classic SharePoint?

Comment: I am passing the access token which i am getting when i am hitting the graph explore 
this url https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer/preview if you hit you an see you wil get an accesstoken that token i am passing the header in the postman an in my ajaz cal it ia working i want to know how to get that access token via code

Comment: @ZMS Consider using the edit option on your Question to add in information.

Comment: @ZMS - I got that part in question but my question is where are your ajax call? Is it in separate solution? If yes, what kind of solution is it? If no, where are you writing that call?